# How to use configuration manager in .net core 3.1

Tags: .net-core-3.1, configurationmanager

I have a package reference in my project which is a .Net core XUnit Test project. This package has CoverageItem constructor as below

```
public CoverageItem()
{
  this._minimumPercentage = Helper.GetMinimumPercentageValue();
  this._maximumPercentage = Helper.GetMaximumPercentageValue();
  this._minimumCurrency = Helper.GetMinimumCurrencyValue();
  this._maximumCurrency = Helper.GetMaximumCurrencyValue();
  this._minimumDays = Helper.GetMinimumDaysValue();
  this._maximumDays = Helper.GetMaximumDaysValue();
}
```

where the Helper.GetMinimumPercentageValue() is

```
public static int GetMinimumPercentageValue()
{
  int result;
      if (!int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinimumPercentageValue"], NumberStyles.Any, (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result))
          throw new MissingFieldException("ConfigurationFile", "MinimumPercentageValue");
  return result;
}
```

In the test case, I need to create an instance of the CoverageItem as

```
var coverageItem = new CoverageItem();
```

Hence I installed the package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.7.0 and created a new app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>        
    <add key="MinimumPercentageValue" value="1" />
    <add key="MaximumPercentageValue" value="200" />    
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Still my test case fails at the line where it creates the CoverageItem with the exception

> System.MissingFieldException : Field 'ConfigurationFile.MinimumPercentageValue' not found.

Comment: You don't - .NET Core has a *completely* different configuration model that allows you to load configuration settings from JSON files, databases, other services etc. The `ConfigurationManager` package is just a stop-gap measure. If you only have some `appSettings` fields to load though, it's easier to use .NET Core's configuration. The package would make sense if you used Properties (in which case you wouldn't need that `Helper` class), especially in multiple assemblies, in which case you'd have to move and modify a lot of code to migrate

Comment: Yes I know that .Net Core has different configuration model but I want to know is there any work around to work with configuration manager as well since I see [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) page hinting that configuration manager applies to .net core 3.1

Comment: The stop-gap, not workaround, is to use the ConfigurationManager package. The exception is thrown *by your own code* if a value isn't found, so it's completely deceptive. For starters, `MinimumPercentageValue` isn't a field. Second, the code throws when *parsing* fails. That doesn't mean the value is missing, it means parsing failed. What does `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinimumPercentageValue"]` return? What are the contents of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` ?

Comment: Perhaps the settings file is missing or misnamed? Does the test project have a configuration file? .NET Core doesn't provide special treatment to `app.config` files so they aren't copied to `bin\Debug` or renamed to `somapp.exe.config`.

Comment: Yes the Test project has app.config file and I have shown the content of the file in the question.

Comment: But that file has no special meaning in .NET Core so it won't even be copied to the output folder unless you explicitly set it to `Copy Always` or `Copy if newer`.

Comment: Agreed. Though I set the app.config to `Copy Always`, I get null when I read from ` Configuration Manager`

Comment: Because `app.config` alone isn't recognized even by .NET Old. The file needs to have the executable's name. In this case the executable project is the unit test. In a .NET 4.x unit test project, `app.config` would be converted to `projectname.dll.config` in `bin\Debug`

Comment: BTW by now you would have finished the migration to the Configuration subsystem. That's a migration you'll have to do eventually, so why not save time and do it now?